# Converting Key=Value text file to JSON

Tags: node.js, json, key-value, data-conversion

I'm looking for a library to convert a text file to JSON.
Do you know which one has the following behavior?
I already test some libraries but without success.

The source files contains a list of key=value pairs, one key per line.
Converting to correct data type is important, my files has:

- string keys
- number keys
- boolean keys
- object (JSON) keys
- arrays (of simple strings or of JSON objects)

Example

```
name = "test"
version = 3
enabled = true
fruit = {"type":"orange","color":"orange"}
consumers = ["kids", "adults"]
years = [2014, 2015]
fruits = [{"type":"orange","color":"orange"},{"type":"apples","method":"red"}]
```

Expected Result after conversion: Valid JSON (don't need style/identation)

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": 3,
  "enabled": true,
  "fruit": {
    "type": "orange",
    "color": "orange"
  },
  "consumers": [
    "kids",
    "adults"
  ],
  "years": [
    2014,
    2015
  ],
  "fruits": [
    {
      "type": "orange",
      "color": "orange"
    },
    {
      "type": "apples",
      "method": "red"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: how well defined is the input format? it seems like it supports arrays, dictionaries, etc... is there a name for this format? is the sytanx following any particular structure?

Comment: I reread your question and now I see that it is decently well described. If the objects and arrays are already following JSON syntax, I personally would just write my own parser/encoder. I doubt anything already exists that will be perfect for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format you're using isn't standardized so I'm doubtful you'll find a package that can parse it out of the box. Your values do look to be valid JSON primitives so you can leverage `JSON.parse` to parse the right hand side. With that you'd just need a parser to robustly pull out all the raw `[key, value]` pairs, but most parsers probably try to do more than just that which might not be what you want.

If you know the input will always be clean and don't need a completely robust parser, it's not difficult to roll this yourself:

```
const data = fs.readFileSync('./data.txt', {encoding: 'utf8'}).split('\n').filter(Boolean)
const obj = {}
for (const line of data) {
    const [key, val] = line.split(/\s*=\s*(.+)/)
    obj[key] = JSON.parse(val)
}
```